# Variável já declarada JS

Tags: javascript

Galera, será que conseguem me ajudar?

Estou com um problema que só ocorre quando jogo o código no servidor, o JS esta acusando que minha variavel já está declarada porém a mesma não está.

```
VM1051:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'app' has already been declared
at <anonymous>:1:1
at p (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Object.send (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.r._evalUrl (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

VM1051:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'req' has already been declared
at <anonymous>:1:1
at p (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Object.send (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.r._evalUrl (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

VM1056:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'urlUploads' has already been declared
at <anonymous>:1:1
at p (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
at text script (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Nb (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Object.send (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
at Function.r._evalUrl (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
```

A variavel urlUploads esta sendo apenas utilizada no meu index.html

A variavel req esta sendo utilizada no meu arquivo funcoes.js

A variavel app é uma instancia da classe que esta dentro do arquivo funcoes.js

Alguem tem ideia do pq do erro? Caso queiram inspecionar elemento segue o link : [link](http://kz.whentoday.com.br/)

Segue o código

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
      const urlUploads = 'http://localhost:8000/uploads/imagens/';
      const urlWs = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/";
      const urlWsAdmin = urlWs + "admin/";
      const urlWsCliente = urlWs + "cliente/";
      const urlAtual = window.location.href;
      const urlFront = window.location.origin;
  </script>
  <base href='/'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/lib/alert/sweetalert2.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/lib/datatable/datables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="dist/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="http://js.whentoday.com.br/funcoes.v1.js"></script>-->
  <script src="dist/js/funcoes.ecomm.v1.js  "></script>
  <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/lib/navigo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/lib/alert/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/lib/datatable/datables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./rotas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

funcoes.ecomm.v1.js

```
"use strict"; //ecma script
let req;
let query;
let interval;
function Whentoday() {
    this.requisicaoAjax = function(event, callback) {
        //verbo GET,POST, PUT, DELETE
        let verbo = event.verbo === undefined ? 'GET' : event.verbo;
        //url string
        let url = event.url === undefined ? alert("Passar url") : event.url;
        //json caso seja POST e PUT
        let json = event.json;
        //elemento carregarregando, caso n seja passado nada automaticamente atribui ao body
        let elementoCarregando = event.elementoCarregando === undefined ? 'body' : event.elementoCarregando;
        //Mensagem carregando, caso n seja passado atribui false
        let mensagemCarregando = event.mensagemCarregando === undefined ? false : event.mensagemCarregando;
        //se mensagemSucesso ou mensagemErro não for passado z
        let mensagemSucesso = event.mensagemSucesso === undefined ? false : event.mensagemSucesso;
        let mensagemErro = event.mensagemErro === undefined ? false : event.mensagemErro;

        let timeout = event.timeout === undefined ? 100000 : event.timeout;
        let $this = this;
        verbo = verbo.toUpperCase();
        let jsonFinal = event.json;
        if (verbo !== 'GET') {
            if (verbo !== 'DELETE') {
                if (jsonFinal === undefined) {
                    alert("Para requisições sem ser GET ou DELETE é necessario enviar data/json");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        let self = this;
        let requisicao = $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: verbo,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: timeout,
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            headers: {
                'apikey_admin' : localStorage.getItem('apikey_admin'),
                'apikey_cliente' : localStorage.getItem('apikey_cliente')
            },
            beforeSend : function() {
                if (mensagemCarregando != false) {
                    self.mostrarCarregando(elementoCarregando, mensagemCarregando);
                    $(elementoCarregando).css({ "overflow": "initial" });
                }
            }
        });
        let resultadoReq = new Array();

        requisicao.done(function (data) {
            var separar = elementoCarregando.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < separar.length; i++) {
                $("[data-elemento-loading='" + separar[i] + "']").remove();
            }
            if (mensagemSucesso == false) {
            } else if (mensagemSucesso == true)
            {
                $this.mensagemSucesso(data['mensagem']);


            } else
            {
                $this.mensagemSucesso(mensagemSucesso);
            }


            requisicao['resultado'] = data;
        });

        requisicao.fail(function (xhr) {


            var separar = elementoCarregando.split(',');

            for (var i = 0; i < separar.length; i++) {
                separar[i] = separar[i].replace(',', '');
                if (separar[i] === "body")
                {
                    separar[i] === '#conteudo';
                }

                $("[data-elemento-loading='" + separar[i] + "']").remove();
            }

            switch (xhr['status']) {
                case 500:
                    $this.mensagemErro('Ocorreu algum erro no servidor, por favor tente novamente ou recarregue a página');
                    break;
                case 403:
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        localStorage.removeItem('apikey_admin');
                        localStorage.removeItem('apikey_cliente');
                        window.history.go(-1);
                    }, 1000);
                default:
                    if (mensagemErro == false) {
                    } else if (mensagemErro == true)
                    {
                        if(xhr != undefined) {
                            if(xhr['responseJSON'] != undefined)
                            {
                                var vetorErros = xhr['responseJSON']['Erros'];
                                if (vetorErros != undefined) {
                                    let mensagem = '';
                                    for (let erros in vetorErros) {
                                        for (let erros1 in vetorErros[erros]) {
                                            mensagem = vetorErros[erros][erros1] + '<br>' + mensagem;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $this.mensagemErro(mensagem);
                                    return;
                                }

                                if (xhr['responseJSON'] != undefined) {
                                    $this.mensagemErro(xhr['responseJSON']['mensagem']);
                                } else {
                                    $this.mensagemErro('Ocorreu algum erro no servidor.');
                                }
                                for (var i = 0; i < separar.length; i++) {
                                    $("[data-elemento-loading='" + separar[i] + "']").remove();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this.mensagemErro('Ocorreu algum erro no servidor.');
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this.mensagemErro('Ocorreu algum erro no servidor.');
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        $this.mensagemErro(mensagemErro);
                    }
            }



            requisicao['resultado'] = xhr;
        });
        if(callback != undefined)
        {
            callback(requisicao);
        }

    },
    this.mensagemErro = function (mensagem) {
        sweetAlert("Oops...", mensagem, "error");
    },
    this.mensagemSucesso = function (mensagem) {
        sweetAlert("OK!", mensagem, "success");
    },
    this.mostrarCarregando= function(elemento, mensagem) {
        $(elemento).css({ 'position': 'relative', 'min-height': '100%;' });
        $(elemento).append(
            '<div class="loading"  data-elemento-loading="' + elemento + '">' +
            '<div class="loader"></div>' +
            '<div data-mensagem="true" class="textoCarregando">' + mensagem + '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );

        if (elemento === 'body') {
            $('[data-elemento-loading="' + elemento + '"]').css("position", "fixed");

        }
        $(elemento).css("overflow", "hidden");
    },
    this.removerCarregando= function (elemento) {
        $("[data-elemento-loading='" + elemento + "']").remove();
        $(elemento).css({ "overflow": "initial" });
    },
    this.carregarComponente = function(event, callback = false) {
        let url = event.url;
        let id = event.id == undefined ? 'pages' : event.id;
        let protegido = event.protegido == undefined ? true : event.protegido;
        let tipo = event.tipo == undefined ? 'admin' : 'cliente';
        let masterPage = null;
        if(tipo == 'admin')
        {
            masterPage = '/componentes/admin/master-page.html';
        }
        if(tipo == 'cliente')
        {
            masterPage = '/componentes/cliente/master-page.html'
        }
        if(masterPage == null)
        {
            alert('Tipo apenas admin ou cliente.');
            return;
        }
        query = event.query;

        if(!protegido)
        {
            $( "body" ).load(masterPage, function () {
                $( "#"+id ).load(url);
            });
        }
        else {
            let apikeyAdmin = localStorage.getItem('apikey_admin');
            let apikeyCliente = localStorage.getItem('apikey_cliente');


            if(tipo == 'admin')
            {
                if(apikeyAdmin == '' || apikeyAdmin == undefined || apikeyAdmin == null){
                    window.location.href = './admin/login';
                    return;
                }
            }
            if(tipo == 'cliente')
            {
                if(apikeyCliente == '' || apikeyCliente == undefined || apikeyCliente == null){
                    window.location.href = '. /login';
                    return;
                }
            }


            $( "body" ).load(masterPage, function () {
                $( "#"+id ).load(url);
            });
        }
        if(callback != false)
        {
            callback();
        }
    },
    this.carregarHtml = function(event, callback = false) {

        let url = event.url;
        let id = event.id == undefined ? 'pages' : event.id;
        let protegido = event.protegido == undefined ? false : event.protegido;

        if(!protegido) {
            $("body").load(url);
        }
        else
        {
            let apikey = localStorage.getItem('apikey');
            if(apikey == '' || apikey == undefined || apikey == null){
                window.location.href = './login';
            }
            $("body").load(url);
        }
        if(callback != false)
        {
            callback();
        }
    },
    this.montarBreadcrumb = function(titulo, event){
        setTimeout(function () {
            var caminho = event;

            $('#breadcrumb').prepend('<ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>');

            $('#breadcrumb').prepend('<h2>'+titulo+'</h2>');
            for(let i in caminho){
                let dados = caminho[i];
                let urlBoolean = dados[0];
                let tituloUrl = dados[1];
                let url = dados[2];



                if(urlBoolean == true)
                {
                    $('#breadcrumb .breadcrumb').append(
                        "<li>"+
                        "<a href='"+url+"'>"+tituloUrl+"</a>"+
                        "</li>"
                    );
                }
                else{
                    $('#breadcrumb .breadcrumb').append(
                        "<li>"+
                        "<a>"+tituloUrl+"</a>"+
                        "</li>"
                    );
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    this.getPayloadJwt = function (item = 'apikey_admin') {
        var token = localStorage.getItem(item);
        if(token != undefined)
        {
            let base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            let base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
            return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
        }
    },
    this.montarMenu = function (event) {
        //montando o menu
        for(let i in event['menu'])
        {

            let menu = event['menu'][i];
            let nome = menu['nomeFront'];
            let url = menu['urlFront'];
            let icon = menu['icone'] == undefined ? '' : menu['icone'];
            $('#side-menu').append(
                '<li data-idMenu="'+i+'">' +
                ' <a href="'+url+'">'+icon+' <span class="nav-label">'+nome+'</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>'+
                '</li>'
            );
        }
        //montando submenu

        for(let i in event['submenu'])
        {
            let submenu = event['submenu'][i];
            let nome = submenu['nome'];
            let url = submenu['url'];
            let icon = submenu['icon'] == undefined ? '' : submenu['icon'];
            let idMenu = submenu['idMenu'];
            $('#side-menu [data-idMenu="'+idMenu+'"]').append(
                '<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">' +
                '<li><a href="'+url+'">'+icon+nome+'</a></li>' +
                '</ul>'
            );
        }

    },
    this.formJson = function (elemento) {
        var loginForm = $(elemento).serializeArray();
        var loginFormObject = {};
        $.each(
            loginForm,
            function(i, v) {
                if(v.value != '')
                {
                    loginFormObject[v.name] = v.value;
                }

            }
        );
        return loginFormObject;
    },
    this.limparInputModal = function (elemento) {
        $(elemento + ' input').each(function () {
            $(this).val('');
        })
    }
};
```

rotas.js

```
"use strict"; //ecma script
let app = new Whentoday();
let router = new Navigo(urlFront, false, '#!');
//rotas de admin
router.on({
    'admin/login': (query) => {
        app.carregarHtml({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Login.html',
            'query' : query
        })
    },
    'admin': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Dashboard.html',
            'query' : query
        })
    },
    'admin/usuarios': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Usuarios.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/clientes': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Clientes.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Clientes',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin']
            })
        });
    },
    'admin/clientes/:id/enderecos': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/EnderecoCliente.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Endereço Cliente',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './'],
                1 : [true, 'Clientes', './admin/clientes'],
                2 : [false, query.id, './admin/clientes']
            })
        });
    },

    'admin/clientes/:id/contatos': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/ContatoCliente.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Contatos Cliente',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './'],
                1 : [true, 'Clientes', './admin/clientes'],
                2 : [false, query.id, './admin/clientes'],
                3 : [false, 'Contatos', './admin/clientes'],
            })
        });
    },
    'admin/forma-pagamento': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/formapgto.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Formas de Pagamento',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });
    },
    'admin/menus': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Menus.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Menus',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/permissoes': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Permissoes.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Permissões',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/categoria': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Categoria.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Categorias',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/produtos': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Produto.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Produtos',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/produtos/cadastrar': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Produto-cadastrar.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Cadastrar',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
                1 : [true, 'Produtos', './admin/produtos'],
                2 : [false, 'Cadastrar', './admin/produtos']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/produto/:id/editar': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Produto-editar.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Editar',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
                1 : [true, 'Produtos', './admin/produtos'],
                2 : [false, query.id, './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/tabelas-preco': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Tabelas-preco.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Tabelas de preço',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/tabelas-preco/:id': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Tabelas-preco-precos.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Produtos da tabela de preço',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
                1: [true, 'Tabelas de preço', 'admin/tabelas-preco'],
                2 : [false, query.id, './admin']
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/estoque': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Estoque.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Estoque',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
            })
        });

    },
    'admin/banners': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Admin/Banners.html',
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Banners',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './admin'],
            })
        });

    },
});
//rotas de cliente
router.on({
    'login': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Cliente/Login.html',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query' : query,
            'tipo' : 'cliente'
        })
    },
    'produto/:nomeProduto': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Cliente/Produto.html',
            'tipo' :  'cliente',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });

    },
    'produto/:nomeProduto/sem-login': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url' : './componentes/Cliente/Produto-semLogin.html',
            'tipo' :  'cliente',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query' : query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários',{
                0 : [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });

    },
    'checkout': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url': './componentes/Cliente/Checkout.html',
            'tipo' :  'cliente',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query': query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários', {
                0: [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });
    },
    'pedido': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url': './componentes/Cliente/Pedido.html',
            'tipo' :  'cliente',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query': query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários', {
                0: [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });
    },
    'categoria/*': (query) => {
        app.carregarComponente({
            'url': './componentes/Cliente/Categoria.html',
            'tipo' :  'cliente',
            'protegido' : false,
            'query': query
        }, function () {
            app.montarBreadcrumb('Usuários', {
                0: [true, 'Home', './']
            })
        });
    }
});

// rota principal
router.on((query) => {
    app.carregarComponente({
        'url' : './componentes/Cliente/Home.html',
        'tipo' :  'cliente',
        'protegido' : false,
        'query' : query
    })
});

// pagina não encontrada
router.notFound((query) => {
    app.carregarHtml({
        'url' : './componentes/Erros/404.html',
        'query' : query,
        'protegido' : false
    })
})
router.resolve();

// setInterval(function () {
//     $('a[href="#slider-carousel"] [data-slide="next"]').trigger('click');
//     console.log('c');
// }, 1000);
```

Abs,
Nicolas Dezena

Comment: Poderia postar seu código para podermos ajuda-ló?

Comment: Meu amigo, adicionei o codigo! Obrigado desde ja.

Comment: Opa, você não trabalha com import/export/require? Pode ser que ele esteja identificando essas variáveis em algum script carregado na página que não seja seu. Seria bom você fechar cada arquivo desse num [escopo fechado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Será que o problema não está ocorrendo pelo fato de ao fazer o load de outro html que vai compor a página os scripts estão sendo re-importados?

Comment: Galera resolvi o problema com a ajuda de um amigo, coloquei uma função auto executável encapsulando o conteúdo dos arquivos.